# Android Native Browser Detection Trough User Agent Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, android-webview, user-agent

Trying to recognise **Android Native Browser** using **only** its user agent with regular expression in Javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I came up with, its pretty long and I wonder if it can be shortened:

`/.*(Linux;.*AppleWebKit.*Version\/\d+\.\d+.*Mobile).*/gi`

Explanation and remarks:

- Does not detect any of the mentioned here: [Safari](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Safari/), [Chrome](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/), [Different Mobile](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Mobile%20Browserlist/).
- Does detect 19 out of 20 mentioned here: [Android Native](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Android%20Webkit%20Browser/), the one that is not getting detected does not comply with googles instructions ([Google Developer](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent#webview_user_agent))

  > If you’re attempting to differentiate between the WebView and Chrome
  >   for Android, you should look for the presence of the Version/*X.X*
  >   string in the WebView user-agent string.
- Tried it without using 'Linux' but got false positive on safari browsers.